# Gradle - define a Maven repository for a specific group

Tags: gradle

My Gradle implementation uses Maven Central and a local repository that stores my company's jars. Is there a way to tell Gradle that only dependencies with group 'com.myCompany' should be searched for in the local repository? I'm getting errors when public jars are not found in my local repo and thought this may be a way to work around that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, that this is possible. But if you get errors, when public jars are not found in your local repo, this is most likely a problem of your private repo. It should return a correct HTTP 404 when a requested jar is not found. I had issues in the past with Archiva. But there exists an option for this in Archiva.

A workaround might be to change the order of the repos in your buildscript:

instead of

```
repositories {
    maven { url:...}
    mavenCentral()
}
```

try

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url:...}
}
```

In that case Gradle will first try mavenCentral, which does behave correctly, and only your local repository last.

Comment: That's what I have currently, but it poses a minor security issue where my jar names are exposed.

Comment: What does happen, if you try to download a public jar from your maven repository, eg. http://local-maven-repo/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.10/slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar with your browser? Do you get a 404 not-found?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it [is possible](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:declaring-repository-filter). Example:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://artifacts.myCompany.com/m2_repo"
        content {
            includeGroup "com.myCompany"
        }
    }
}
```